# Is it possible to run and non exe through PsExec

Tags: psexec, streamdeck

What I am trying to do is set up my stream deck to run a CMD Psexec command to open a macro file on the remote system. As far as it goes, using MiniMouseMacro, the macro files are .mmmacro. So far my test say the Psexec could not start, the system could not find the file specified. After double checking. It's looking in the right area on remote system. Just not launching it. The macro program is set to launch and run when the saved macro file is opened

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a different option on doing this. As Psexec doesn't want to open the .mmmacro file. I ended up making batch scripts for Psexec to launch instead. Works great this way. Now I can run a GUI application remotely